Problems with code to solve nonlinear ODE applied to BEC
Strictly I must solve my problem with an asymptotic approximation carried out by the series method. The code I have made is the following to solve my problem
$$ R''(s) + \frac{1}{s}R'(s) - \frac{1}{s^2}R(s)+R(s)-R(s)^3=0 $$
with $R(s=0)=0$, $R'(0)= \lambda $, and $R(s \to \infty )= 1$.
Actualization 2.0:
R[s_] = \[Lambda]s + Sum[a[n] s^n, {n, 2, 20}];
ser = series[
  D[R[s], {s, 2}] + 1/s D[R[s], s] - 1/s^2 R[s] + R[s] - R[s]^3/.s-->x, {x, 
   0, 20}];
ecuaciones = 
  Table[SeriesCoefficient[ser, {x, 0, n}] == 0, {n, 0, 20}];
solucion = Solve[ecuaciones, Table[a[n], {n, 2, 20}]];
solucion



Why do you think your problem can be solved in this manner? What method are you trying to automate? If you give a bit more background info, we'll be able to help you better. 2. You've mixed up function value and function relationship, compare outputs of D[R[s], s] and D[R, s] and think about what's happening here. 3. In the definition of sol, k and b suddenly show up, which doesn't seem to make sense. 4. The output of Series needs to be Normaled, see the document for more info. 5. Have you read e.g. https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/ ?


Because I tried AsymtopticDSolve but it doesnt compile correctly. Our instructor show us this kind of solution but I have troubles to understand it. Thanks for the link!

And your observation is correct. I'm tryin' to catch odd and even coeff. because naturally (using without it) I can't answer my problem, ando in this form, neither haha :( Only tried to do something different. I'm also using examples related to this question but nothing.

It helps to have the right syntax for the derivative terms: D[R[s], {s, 2}] + 1/s D[R[s], s] - 1/s^2 R[s] + R[s] - R[s]^3.

It looks like a radial Ginsburg-Landau equation with s-dependent term in front of R(s). Here, s plays the role of a radius. I do not think that one can obtain an analytical solution or analytical approximation of such an equation that would be valid at all s: 0<s<infinity. The more that it exhibits a bifurcation at lambda slightly exceeding 1.

In this particular case I know by shooting Star method than lambda is 0.45... approx. My problem radicate in the use of mathematica to solve this kind of problems. Usually, I prefer to use Python and it's work better for me.

@Litafie Your "ansatz" R[s]=... can't fulfill the bc R[Infinity]==1 I think

This conditions are in the problem.

I'm trying to do an Asymtoptic Approx. Using Taylor series, this is the problem suggested by my course. Under this conditions and using sympy in a Python code I could get an answer in the past, but I need to understand how use mathematica to solve this kind of problems :(


When there're more than one commenter other than you, you need to add e.g. @AlexeiBoulbitch in your comment, otherwise we won't get the reminder. 2. If you know how to use sympy to solve your problem, I believe Mathematica won't be difficult for you, because languages for symbolic calculation are just similar. Can you show us your sympy code so we can understand what you're trying to achieve easier? 3. Notice series should be Series, and remember all the built-in functions are starting with capital letter, and their colors are usually black, not blue.


This problem can be solved using Reduce and Solve as follows
nmax = 20; R = Sum[a[n] s^n, {n, 0, nmax}];
ser = Series[
   s^2 D[R, {s, 2}] + s  D[R, s] - R + s^2 R - s^2 R^3, {s, 0, 
    nmax}];
ecuaciones = 
 Table[SeriesCoefficient[ser, {s, 0, n}], {n, 0, nmax}]; solucion = 
 Reduce[Table[ecuaciones[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ecuaciones]}], 
  Table[a[n], {n, 2, nmax}]];

sol = Quiet@Solve[solucion, Table[a[n], {n, 0, nmax}]]
{{a[0] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> -(a[1]/8), a[4] -> 0, 
  a[5] -> 1/192 (a[1] + 8 a[1]^3), a[6] -> 0, 
  a[7] -> (-a[1] - 80 a[1]^3)/9216, a[8] -> 0, 
  a[9] -> (a[1] + 656 a[1]^3 + 1152 a[1]^5)/737280, a[10] -> 0, 
  a[11] -> (-a[1] - 5216 a[1]^3 - 43392 a[1]^5)/88473600, a[12] -> 0, 
  a[13] -> (a[1] + 41576 a[1]^3 + 1143552 a[1]^5 + 875520 a[1]^7)/
   14863564800, a[14] -> 0, 
  a[15] -> (-a[1] - 334400 a[1]^3 - 26593536 a[1]^5 - 
    82096128 a[1]^7)/3329438515200, a[16] -> 0, 
  a[17] -> (
   a[1] + 2715296 a[1]^3 + 588605952 a[1]^5 + 4968407040 a[1]^7 + 
    2129756160 a[1]^9)/958878292377600, a[18] -> 0, 
  a[19] -> (-a[1] - 22239104 a[1]^3 - 12795087360 a[1]^5 - 
    250548781056 a[1]^7 - 401198776320 a[1]^9)/345196185255936000, 
  a[20] -> 0}}

Note, that we should solve BVP and define $\lambda$ as well. For this we use NDSolve in a form of
s0 = 10^-6; s1 = 4.; sol1 = 
 NDSolve[{D[R1[s], {s, 2}] + 1/s D[R1[s], s] - 1/s^2 R1[s] + R1[s] - 
     R1[s]^3 == 0, R1[s0] == 0, R1[s1] == 1}, R1, {s, s0, s1}];

Actually this is not so good solution since R1'[s] has a jump at s=s0, nevertheless we can define $\lambda$ as
lambda = .5 R1'[s0] /. sol1[[1]]

Out[]= 0.585944

With this parameter we can compare numeric and asymptotic solution
Plot[{Evaluate[R /. sol[[1]] /. a[1] -> lambda], 
  R1[s] /. sol1[[1]]}, {s, s0, 2.2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Asymptotic", "Numeric"}]


Please note, that first derivative R1'[s] has unexplained jump
Plot[{Evaluate[D[R, s] /. sol[[1]] /. a[1] -> lambda], 
  R1'[s] /. sol1[[1]]}, {s, s0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Asymptotic", "Numeric"}]


Nevertheless we have a good agreement in amplitude and first derivative as well in a region $s\le 1.5$.
Update 1 Thanks to Ulrich Neumann suggestion we can try solve BVP with Mathematica FEM as well, we have, for example
s0 = 0; s1 = 7.; sol1 = 
 NDSolve[{D[R1[s], {s, 2}] + 1/s D[R1[s], s] - 1/s^2 R1[s] + R1[s] - 
     R1[s]^3 == 0, R1[s0] == 0, R1[s1] == 1}, R1, {s, s0, s1}, 
  Method -> "FiniteElement", 
  "InitialSeeding" -> {R1[s] == 1 - Exp[-s]}]

There are two messages about the Damkoehler number and the Peclet number, but nevertheless we can compare FEM solution with the asymptotic solution using
lambda = R1'[s0] /. sol1[[1]]

Out[]= 0.586062

Visualization
{Plot[{Evaluate[R /. sol[[1]] /. a[1] -> lambda], 
   R1[s] /. sol1[[1]]}, {s, s0, 2.2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Asymptotic", "Numeric"}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"s", "R"}], 
 Plot[{Evaluate[D[R, s] /. sol[[1]] /. a[1] -> lambda], 
   R1'[s] /. sol1[[1]]}, {s, s0, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue}, {Red, Dashed}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Asymptotic", "Numeric"}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"s", "R'"}]}


Note, that there is no jump in FEM solution at s=0.

You can improve your NDSolve sol1 solution : s0 =0; s1 =50.;  (*~ \[Infinity]*)sol1 =   NDSolveValue[{odeR == 0, R[s0] == 0, R [s1] == 1}, R , {s, s0, s1},    Method -> "FiniteElement",    "InitialSeeding" -> {R[s] == 1 - Exp[-s]}]

@UlrichNeumann Thank you very much for you suggestion.  Actually FEM solution is also failed with two messages about the Damkoehler number and the Peclet number, but we can compare it with asymptotic one with x1=7 for example.

FEM solution gives a message, seems ok(I compared with FDM solution and manual Galerkin)

@UlrichNeumann Why not to post your solutions?

Because I can't contribute to a better asymptotic solution. Actually I try asymptotic R[s]~ 1 + Sum[a[k]/(1 + s)^k, {k, 1, n}] ...

Thanks to much!

@Litafie You are welcome!

I finally managed to make a code that also properly returned the coefficients and I would like to share it with you.
R[s_] := lambda s + Sum[a[n] s^n, {n, 2, 20}]

DR = D[R[s], s]
DR2 = D[DR, s]

ecuacionDiferencial = DR2 + DR/s - 1/2 R[s]/s^2 + R[s] - R[s]^3

serie = Series[ecuacionDiferencial, {s, 0, 20}]

ecuaciones = Table[SeriesCoefficient[serie, n] == 0, {n, 2, 20}]


solucion = Solve[ecuaciones, Table[a[n], {n, 2, 20}]]


solucion

